# how can I set additional information in openAM?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, openam

I am using openAM for authentication of our applications. OpenAM is using LDAP. I am using HTTP_HEADER to get username as below.

```
String userid = request.getHeader("HTTP_REMOTE_UID");
userid = userid != null ? userid.trim() : null;
```

Right now, I am getting only user name but I need some more information also like city, country...etc.

Can anybody please tell me how can I set addition information in openAM so that I can fetch it from HTTP HEADER?

I am new bee for OPENAM, so please ignore the question if it's useless question.

Thanks in advance for you valuable time.

Comment: Is you application protected by a Policy Agent? or are you connecting to OpenAM directly using the REST API?

Comment: @GuillermoR It's protected by policy agent. We are not using REST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the attribute is stored in LDAP as part of the user entry then follow these steps:

1. Login to the admin console.
2. Go to *Access Control > REALM_NAME > Data Stores > DATASTORE_NAME > LDAP User Attributes* and make sure the attribute is listed there.
3. Go to *Access Control > REALM_NAME > Agents > J2EE > AGENT_NAME > Application > General > Profile Attributes Processing* and add a mapping for your new attribute: [ldap_attr_name]=header_name (i.e [mail]=EMAIL_HEADER, [cn]=CN_HEADER, etc...).
4. Make sure the *Profile Attribute Fetch Mode* is set to HTTP_HEADER.
5. (Optional) Bounce Policy Agent if notifications are disabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: bouncing the agent is only needed if notification mode is not configured at all or configured incorreclty